# Finding the Euler-Lagrange operator $\mathcal M$ of a functional $\mathcal F$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'd appreciate some help with the following problem:

> Let $F = F(x, \{p_\alpha\}_{|\alpha|\le m})$ be a smooth function of the variables $x\in \overline \Omega$, and $p_\alpha \in \mathbb R, |\alpha|\le m$. Find the Euler-Lagrange operator $\mathcal M$ of the functional $$\mathcal F(u) = \int_\Omega F(x, \{D^\alpha u\}) \, dx$$ and show that its linearization at a smooth funciton $u_0$ is the operator $D^\beta(a_{\alpha \beta} D^\alpha u)$, where $a_{\alpha \beta}(x) = F_{p_\alpha p_\beta}(x,\{D^\delta u_0(x_0)\}_{|\delta |\le m}$. (The subscripts $p_\alpha, p_\beta$ here denote partial derivatives; also, recall that the linearization of $\mathcal M(u)$ at $u_0$ is given by $\mathcal L(v) = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \mathcal M(u_0+sv)$.)

$\Omega$ presumably is some bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ (but you may assume any niceness conditions necessary).

I must admit, I'm not quite sure what is meant by the "Euler-Lagrange operator" of a functional $\mathcal F$. Google couldn't explain it to me, either. So I'm asking here.

---

I know that one normally looks for a stationary part of the functional in hope of finding a minimizer/maximizer. So I simply tried differenting under the integral sign to see what comes out: For an extremal point $u$ and any function $\varphi$ we have

\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \mathcal F(u+s\varphi) \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \sum_{\alpha} F_{p_\alpha}(x,\{D^\delta u\}) D^\alpha \varphi \, dx \\
&= \int_{\Omega}\left[ \sum_{\alpha} (-1)^{|\alpha|} D^\alpha \left(F_{p_\alpha}(x,\{D^\delta u\})\right) \right] \varphi \, dx
\end{align}

which implies $\sum_{\alpha} (-1)^{|\alpha|} D^\alpha \left(F_{p_\alpha}(x,\{D^\delta u\})\right) = 0$. Should I try to go on from here? I this what I'm supposed to do at all? If yes, is there a way to avoid a messy calculation in trying to evaluate $D^\alpha \left(F_{p_\alpha}(x,\{D^\delta u\})\right)$?
 And what is this $\mathcal M$ in the exercise statement?

I think the exercise is largely to motivate why we might be interested in the properties of equations of the form 
$$\sum_{|\alpha|, |\beta| \le m} D^\beta (a_{\alpha \beta} D^\alpha u) = \sum_{|\beta|\le m} D^\beta f_\beta$$
which were the content of the last chapter. So I would like to understand this in some detail. Also, I could not find a definition of the Euler-Lagrange operator $\mathcal M$ in any earlier notes, either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume the EL operator for this problem is $$\mathcal{M}:u\mapsto\sum_\alpha(-1)^{|\alpha|}D^\alpha\left(F_{p_\alpha}(x,\{D^\sigma u\})\right),$$ and you're allowed to use the $a_{\alpha\beta}$ abbreviation to verify the linearization.

Comment: @anon: Thanks for the commment! I think you're probably right.

Comment: @Sam I just encountered this post while trying to learn about linearizations of PDE. I was hoping you could clarify a few things:

 Are you using einstein summation for $\alpha$ in your expression for $\mathcal{L}$? Is the sum in your answer to your own question taken over $|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq m$? Also, do you happen to remember what book the original question stems from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\mathcal M(u) = \sum_\beta (-1)^{|\beta|}D^\alpha(F_{p_\beta}(x,\{D^\sigma u\})$ as was pointed out above. From the definition of $\mathcal L$, we derive
\begin{align}
\mathcal L(v) 
&= \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \mathcal M(u+tv) \\
&= \sum_\beta (-1)^{|\beta|}D^\beta(F_{p_\alpha p_\beta}(x,\{D^\sigma u\})D^\alpha v) \\
&= \sum_\beta (-1)^{|\beta|}D^\beta(a_{\alpha \beta}D^\alpha v).
\end{align}